# Nice way to write an unsatisfiable constraint?

Tags: haskell

I've found myself writing this:

```
data T1
data T2

type Unsatisfiable = T1 ~ T2
```

So I can do something like this:

```
type family NEq t1 t2 :: Constraint where
  NEq t t = Unsatisfiable
  NEq _ _ = ()

type HasProxyT t = NEq t (ProxyT t)
```

Then I can use `HasProxyT` to restrict default methods to not loop if the proxy type is the same as themselves (doesn't stop two instances from looping to each other's default methods, but you'd have to be pretty stupid to do such a thing).

But the definition of `Unsatisfiable` seems a bit ugly? Is there a nicer way of defining `Unsatisfiable` or is this just the way it's done?

Comment: On recent versions of GHC you can use [`TypeError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:TypeError)

Comment: @user2407038 cheers that’ll do nicely thanks. If you want to make that the answer I’ll tick it.

Comment: You can use [`Bottom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Bottom) too.

Comment: What is `ProxyT` for? What is it's kind? What do its instances look like? I'm wondering if there might be a more constructive approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On recent versions of GHC you can use [`TypeError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:TypeError):

```
import GHC.TypeLits 

type Unsatisfiable = TypeError ('Text "oops")
```

However, I recommend you just use `TypeError` directly at use sites and give a custom error message:

```
type family NEq t1 t2 :: Constraint where
  NEq t t = TypeError ('Text "Expected a type distinct from " ':<>: 'ShowType t)
  NEq _ _ = ()
```